# Can CSS be disabled in any browser?

Tags: css

Is it possible for Cascading Style Sheets be disabled in any browser?

I am also including legacy versions in this question, maybe as far back as IE 6?

Comment: I believe most browsers have a way to disable styles, but is there any particular reason why you ask this?

Comment: From the moment your webpage hits an end-user, it's stored on their computer, they can do whatever they want to it.

Comment: I'm going to charitably assume this is a programming question. Is there are particular part of the Firefox or Chromium codebase you're trying to modify to disable CSS that's not working? What did you try?

Comment: Should this question be moved to [SuperUser](http://superuser.com/)?

Comment: Maybe, but even there it might be just asking for a list of all browsers and if they have a certain feature? If it is 'any', then the answer is yes, but the 'as far back' implies there is a list expected...

Comment: Thanks for the replies, not happy with being down voted, I am just asking to know how vulnerable a template that I am working on is to being broken, but since CSS shouldn't pose any security threats I don't see why anyone should bother...

Comment: It's actually a good question, considering that some browsers (selectively) allow enabling/disabling various content-types and HTML related features...

Comment: Thanks GLES, is it possible to embed malicious code in an image and have it executed somehow? I have an idea how this might be done if JavaScript was enabled...don't know if it will work though...

Answer (score 2):

Don't know about CSS, but the following can be

- Images
- JavaScript
- Plug-ins
- Media

as seen here (in Chrome)

[image: Chrome]

Answer (score 1):

Yes, in most browsers it is possible. E.g. in Firefox it is View → Page Style → No Style. Generally this feature can be added to any browser as CSS is processed client-side, but surely it can be also removed from or not implemented in any browser.

If you want to disable it from server-side, just don’t include the `link` element linking the stylesheet to the HTML document.